# Form input to http post request

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular Bootstrap project- a form with some fields like name, email, phone, etc. to fill in. The form is written in HTML, in a file called customer-form.component.html. Upon submission, a JSON object is created with the values of the fields and displayed on-screen.

I am writing a HTTP POST request in the file customer-form.component.ts. The method in question looks like this:

```
postProfile() {
this.httpClient.post('API server url', 
{
  name:this.name,
  phone:this.phone,
  email:this.email,
  yesorno:this.yesorno
})
.subscribe(
  (data:any) => {
    console.log(data)
  }
)}
```

I set it up so submission of the form would also submit the POST request to the server. I am using Chrome to debug, and in the console I get the error message:

"Failed to INSERT or UPDATE Customer record due to: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'NAME' cannot be null]"

I changed the code to `name:name` once, and a submission got through. But when I checked it in the server, it had a blank name (`name:''`), and some true/false fields and fill-in numerical fields. Email and phone were not even represented, blank or otherwise, in the submission. Now if I try to submit something with `name:name`, it is counted as a duplicate and does not work. No matter what I fill in the form before I submit, the complaint is that the name field is blank.

**My main question:** Is there a way, preferably by referring to the JSON object, to accurately populate the POST request fields based on input fields? The JSON object is defined/created in a script in the index.html file.

My second question: What on earth is being used to populate the POST request right now? Even if I fill in the fields, the name field is blank upon submission. I have a model Customer object in customer-form.component.ts (like below), and I suspect that is how the original submission was populated (except the name?).

`model = new Customer('Harry', 11111111111111, 'pott@r', true);`

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: did you try invoking the POST request with hard coded request parameter/data ? and get the same SQL error ?

Comment: Hard-coded data works, no error, and all the fields are represented correctly.

Comment: if the hard coded data works without error then that just tell us there is a problem on how do you get the data from the input fields. how do you get data from those field you have mention?

Comment: That's my question, I don't know how to grab that input from customer-form.component.html and pipe it to customer-form.component.ts. "this.name" doesn't work, so I tried referring to the JSON object which was created in the html file. That is not recognized in the ts file either.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and verifiable sample of those two file? i.e., customer-form.component.html and customer-form.component.ts .